# Why does $\nabla^2$ only have second order derivatives?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Why is $\nabla^2f(x,y,z) = f_x''f_yf_z+f_y''f_xf_z+f_z''f_xf_y$ where $f(x,y,z)= f_xf_yf_z$

From my understanding $\nabla^2f(x,y,z) = \nabla(\nabla f(x,y,z) = \nabla(f_x'f_yf_z + f_y'f_xf_z + f_z'f_xf_y)$;
so why are there no $f'_xf'_yf_z $ terms in the final answer?

Comment: This is total confusion. First you use $f$ for $f_xf_yf_z$. That is abuse of notation. Next, does $f_x$ stand for the partial derivative? What does prime mean? Last, $\nabla^2$ usually means the Laplacian. I do not know what you mean by the gradient of the gradient.

Comment: @TedShifrin my apologies for the confusion, I meant $f_x$ as a separate function, that is f is the product of three functions $f_x$, $f_y$ and $f_z$. Could you suggest how I can edit the notation to make it more clear?

Comment: Welcome to MSE !

Comment: It still is a mess. The only way the desired answer is valid is if $f_x$ is a function of $x$ only, etc.

Comment: Yea what exactly is going on with the definition here? Should it not be just $f_{xx} + f_{yy} + f_{zz}$ for the laplacian? @AntoinRoquentin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moniker $\nabla^2$ is a bit a misnomer, its a self dot product with operator composition not a nested gradient (which should produce a square matrix)  NOR a literal multiplicative squaring. We do our calculations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ here. If $\nabla$  denotes the gradient we can spell it below as:

$$ \nabla[f] = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix}  $$

It's an abuse of notation but we can now try to define $\nabla \cdot \nabla$  which is a dot product. When taking this dot product $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is not the literal square (as in self multiplication) of the operator but is instead the composition. So it is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ meaning "second derivative". Not square of first derivative. We see then that the standard laplacian defined as

$$ \nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z^2} = \nabla \cdot \nabla $$

And that that self dot product is "kind of like" a square. I'm a big fan of Physicist operator abuse of notation generally (since it usually works well and reveals a lot of insight) but the jump from $\nabla \cdot \nabla \rightarrow \nabla^2$ feels like poor taste. There are just too many different meanings to $\nabla^2$ to be able to make it obvious what its meaning should be so I would personally prefer not to abuse the notation past the dot product.

Comment: Ah OK this makes sense, because it is a dot product then it would cancel out the terms with the x-hat and y-hat. Thanks a lot! I was interpreting it as simply taking the gradient two times. I didn't realize it was a dot product, thanks for your insight!

Comment: yea so to literally take the gradient twice would product instead a square matrix called a Hessian. That too is useful and is imo a just as valid thing to assign to $\nabla^2$ as the laplacian but historical precedent has already fixed the definitions for us unfortunately. (In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the other operator to consider is $\nabla \times \nabla$ but this is always $0$ since the partial derivatives commute)